# React native Expo Build Number does not Increase

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to build version "1.2.0" i have changed every single "buildNumber" and "version" in app.json and expo still builds ios buildNumber: "1.0.0". I am using
`eas build --profile production --platform ios`

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Redacted",
    "slug": "Redacted",
    "description":"Redacted",
    "version": "1.2.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/mark.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/TRANSPARENT2.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "buildNumber": "1.2",
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSFaceIDUsageDescription": "This app uses the FaceID feature to login. If faceID fails or if it is not available for any reason, the app will fall back to a standard login system."
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "CAMERA",
        "USE_FINGERPRINT",
        "USE_BIOMETRIC",
        "VIBRATE"
      ],
      "package": "Redacted"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-notifications",
        {
          "icon": "./assets/DarkVersion.png",
          "color": "#d2282e",
          "sounds": [
            "./assets/notification.m4r"
          ]
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

#### This is what i get on expo.dev...I cant submit the app because of this.

[image: expo build]

#### And here is the error in the console.

[image]

Answer (score 26):

**Same Experience**

I had a similar experience updating the app.json file in my-expo-project.
I kept the version string the same `0.9.9` and only changed the build number string from `124` to `125`.

Running `eas build --profile production --platform iOS` resulted in the same console error.

> You've already submitted this version of the app.

The build summary on expo.dev showed the old build number was delivered.

[image: Older build number delivered to expo.dev1]

**Solution**

Turns out I had to use the `expo prebuild` command to resolve this.

```
➜  my-expo-project git:(v125) $ expo prebuild
✔ Created native projects | /android, /ios already created | gitignore already synced
✔ Updated package.json and added index.js entry point for iOS and Android
 Using npm to install packages.
✔ Cleaned JavaScript dependencies 3698ms
✔ Installed JavaScript dependencies 11150ms
✔ Config synced
```

Now that the app config is synced to the `./iOS` and `./Android` folders `eas build --profile production --platform iOS` now delivers the correct bundle and build number to expo.dev

[image: Correct build number delivered to expo.dev2]

Answer (score 4):

Turns out `eas build --profile production --platform ios` does not update the plist file every time you run it (super lame IMO). You manually need to go into the `./ios/<yourApp>/plist` file and update the `CFBundleVersion` and `CFBundleShortVersionString` keys. This is only a thing after your first run of `eas build --profile production --platform ios`

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have any native code or have not updated native code inside the ios or android folder, you can delete the folders and let EAS handle the builds for you. Without those folders, `eas build -p ios` with or without `--local` will update the build numbers from the app.json file.

If you want to keep the ios and android folders, you'll have to run `npx expo prebuild` as @L4ivi suggested or you can update the version going into ios > info.plist file and update the string value of `CFBundleShortVersionString` for your version number and `CFBundleVersion` for your build number. Or you can open the `.xcworkspace` file to open the project in Xcode and update the version and build number there.

Answer (score 1):

In my case [sdk 47, eas-cli/3.9.2, darwin-x64, node-v19.6.1], with `"appVersionSource": "remote"` in `eas.json` file, changing the `runtimeVersion: { policy: 'appVersion' }` in `app.config.ts` file was helpful.

More read on `runtimeVersion` in [expo documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/eas-update/runtime-versions).

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/app-versions/#remote-version-source) , this will auto increment your build version during the build.

then you can use
`eas submit -p ios --latest` to submit to testflight directly